# Procedure in handling: Multiuser working on one data set

Tags: php, mysql, database, user-controls, software-design

more an approach question, how to deal with the problem:

**What methods, approaches, techniques, ideas or terms can be used for the following problem?**

Several users should be able to access (read, write, recreate, edit) a web address book.
**How do you handle the case that several users are working on one record at the same time?**

E.g. editing or one user reads the record while another user changes it (e.g. phone number), then the reader doesn't even notice that his information is no longer correct and it leads to problems.

**Are there any known (even new) approaches here?**
Bit researched but many entries in forums are already many years old.

Many thanks.

Comment: *How do you handle the case that several users are working on one record at the same time?* I forbid second access to the row using reservation technique.

Comment: For example this site informs the viewer if the question being viewed has been updated and posts a note on viewers browser to say that's the case. No idea how this is achieved but I imagine DB captures the fact of an insert/update/delete and front end polls and based on the tables being accessed pops a message.